# does codeigniter have a supported openid library or plugin?

Tags: codeigniter

I have a project with CodeIgniter that requires openId - the janrain libraries seem overkill. Anything simpler or specific to CI?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built within the core CodeIgniter framework, as it's understood that not everyone would use it, and therefore they would have to add more and more in to cover different options.  This would then lead to the framework being more of a heavyweight, rather than the lightweight they are aiming for.

There's a one which is built on top of the janrain stuff which supposedly makes it easy, according to a [forum post](http://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-32583.html?highlight=openid) in the CI community (only click on the github link, the other's are garbage, which doesn't lead to much confidence in the code; but it hasn't been updated in 5 years.